# Java JDT finding methods

Tags: java, eclipse-jdt

I'm using a visitor system with the Java JDT to read in source code. I am looking to find a method call for example :

```
System.out.println(i);
```

I understand the visitor pattern so I need something like :

```
    public boolean visit(MethodPattern node) {

//code here

}
```

but I don't know what the type of node should be so that I would have access to information in the method call. Such as "i" in the first example or s in the following example:

```
foo(String s)
```

Comment: A great tool to analize your code is the ASTView. It can show you the AST of any code marked in your editor. You can install it into Eclipse from the update site http://www.eclipse.org/jdt/ui/update-site

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't know where you have taken the method signature `visit(MethodPattern node)` from. But you could override [`visit(MethodInvocation node)`](http://help.eclipse.org/kepler/topic/org.eclipse.jdt.doc.isv/reference/api/org/eclipse/jdt/core/dom/ASTVisitor.html#visit(org.eclipse.jdt.core.dom.MethodInvocation)) in order to be able to inspect method invocations. Then you can use [the passed node](http://help.eclipse.org/kepler/index.jsp?topic=%2Forg.eclipse.jdt.doc.isv%2Freference%2Fapi%2Forg%2Feclipse%2Fjdt%2Fcore%2Fdom%2FASTVisitor.html) to query method arguments and the like.

```
public class MyVisitor extends org.eclipse.jdt.core.dom.ASTVisitor {

    public boolean visit(MethodInvocation node) {
        List<?> arguments = node.getArguments();
        // do something with the arguments, etc.
    }
}
```